# std::regex_search and his std::smatch as return value in template

Tags: c++11

Take a look on my code and tell me how to do this proper way. First of all this is part of my config manager class. Generally i want to use read function only with three main types of data int, float, string (maybe bool in futhure).

```
template<typename T>
T Read(const std::string& name)
{
    T retVal;
    std::string buffer;

    while(std::getline(m_hFile, buffer))
    {
        if(strstr(buffer.c_str(), name.c_str()))
        {                
            std::smatch match;
            const std::regex regex_patern("=\"(.*)\"");
            std::regex_search(buffer, match, regex_patern);
            retVal = ????
            break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

How can i cast this std::smatch to get it work? What should i do there? I dont really have idea. Any tips or code snippets are welcome.

Comment: `istringstream istr(result_of_match); istr >> retVal;` See also [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think you get the idea:

```
template<typename T>
T Read(const std::string& name) {
  T retVal;
  std::string buffer;

  while(std::getline(m_hFile, buffer)) {
    if(strstr(buffer.c_str(), name.c_str())) {
      std::smatch match;
      const std::regex regex_patern("=\"(.*)\"");
      std::regex_search(buffer, match, regex_patern);
      if (!match.empty()) {
    std::istreamstream ss(match[0]);
    ss >> retVal;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

I usually use [boost::property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html) to read config files:

```
// json example
// {
//   'foo': 'hello, world',
//   'bar': 1
// }  

boost::property_tree::ptree config;
boost::property_tree::read_json("path", config);
auto hello_world = config.get<std::string>("foo");
auto one = config.get<int>("bar");
```